# From Django1.7 onwards `migration` is into the core. Is it similar to `south`?

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-1.7, django-migrations

I am using `south` for migrations. Today I surprisingly found an interesting article, [django1.7 support migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/).

Interestingly I found that the `startapp` command even creates a folder `migrations`.

```
python manage.py startapp myapp
```

has tree:

```
myapp/
    admin.py
    models.py
    views.py
    tests.py
    migrations/ <-- folder migrations
```

I also found command `./manage.py makemigrations`, is it similar to:

`./manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial` or `./manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto`

So what about `datamigration`??

Also found command `./manage.py migrate`, i hope it is similar to south's `./manage.py migrate` command.

So there is no `./manage.py syncdb` command in `django1.7`??

Comment: Here are your answers:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.7 migrations are successor to South migrations.

And since there are now migrations old syncdb was deprecated. Syncdb should be working still for few versions.

You can read more details what was changed in [1.7 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/#schema-migrations):